# Error during update data on mongo db

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this error during save on update data in  my mongo db.
this is erorr:

> Save can only be used with documents that have an Id.

this is my model:

```
  public ModelKorisici () { }



    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))] // posajvljivaa se greška kod BSON tipa podataka kod ID-a,preuzoteo s dokumentacije drivera 1.5
    public Guid  Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("ime")]
    public string ime { get; set; }


   [BsonElement("prezime")]
    public string prezime { get; set; }


    [BsonElement("lozinka")]
    public string lozinka { get; set; }


    [BsonElement("email")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("kor_ime")]
    public string kor_ime { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("uloga")]
    public string uloga { get; set; }
}
```

My code for update is here:

```
  public void urediKorisnika(ModelKorisici korisnik)
    {
        MongoCollection<ModelKorisici> kljenti = GetTasksCollection();
        kljenti.Save(kljenti);
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do but your error is in following code block

```
public void urediKorisnika(ModelKorisici korisnik)
{
    MongoCollection<ModelKorisici> kljenti = GetTasksCollection();
    kljenti.Save(kljenti);
}
```

Here are you trying to store `collection` to itself. I believe `GetTasksCollection()` return `collection` from MongoDB and then you are trying to store it into itself again. see `kljenti.Save(kljenti);`

You need to create instance of `ModelKorisici` and save it into `kljenti`

Your code should look something like:

```
public void urediKorisnika(ModelKorisici korisnik)
{
    MongoCollection<ModelKorisici> kljenti = GetTasksCollection();

    var model  = new ModelKorisici();
    model.ime = ...
    ...

    kljenti.Save(model);
}
```

Comment: when i do your code, i insert a new object with _id, and other other atributes are null

Comment: This is obvious. you have to fill your properties. `...` in my code means complete rest of initialization. Bottom line is that you are not getting errors  anymore.